# How to use header and showHeaders attributes of p:multiSelectListbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, attributes

In [`<p:multiSelectListbox>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/multiSelectListbox.xhtml), they used attributes `header`  and `showHeaders`. But when I added two attributes to my `<p:multiSelectListbox>`, then I get the message from IDE:

> The attribute header is not defined in the component `<p:multiSelectListbox>`

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What primefaces version are you using?

Comment: I am using primefaces version 5.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header` and `showHeaders` did'nt appear until Primefaces version 5.1 (check the [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation)), so if you can upgrade that'll do it.